# How to resolve 404 Not found: Could not find the controller?

Tags: services

I am new to Drupal and its web services.

I am working on *user forgot password API* by using the [Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) module. Below is my service resource code:

```
function test_api_services_resources() {
    $definition = array(
        'test_api' => array(
            'actions' => array(
                'forgot_password' => array(
                    'help' => 'Reset user password',
                    'callback' => '_test_api_resource_forgot_pass',
                    'args' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'email',
                        'type' => 'string',
                        'description' => 'The user email id',
                        'source' => 'data',
                        'optional' => FALSE,
                    ),
                    ),
                    'access callback' => 'services_access_menu',
                    'file' => array('type' => 'inc', 'module' => 'services', 'name' => 'resources/user_resource'),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),

    return $definition;
}

function _test_api_resource_forgot_pass($email){
    //Just for testing purpose i have returned my input parameter
    return $email;
}
```

Whenever I try to run this in *Firefox Poster addon* I get an error **404 Not found: Could not find the controller**. I don't know what is the exact issue!

Comment: You need to login with token to see OK

Comment: @Stefen login is working in actions but my custom forgot_password only not works in any of ..

Comment: does your arrays and fields are correct? also is the resource is checked on the services?

Comment: The `request_new_password` resource already exists in the Services module: http://cgit.drupalcode.org/services/tree/resources/user_resource.inc#n162 - other than that, clear all your caches and be sure to POST along the X-CSRF-Token with your requests.